# Range.Find() function not finding numerical values - VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I'm having is that if Range().Find finds nothing I'm adding the value to the "Total" sheet but when the loop starts from the beginning the rgFound = Range.Find() is stilling nothing, resulting in a endless loop. 
The problem seems to be that

```
Worksheets("Total").Range("A1:A20000").Find(Worksheets("July").Cells(Index, "C").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Is find values with the following format: 423423_fsd but not numerical values, ex: 42341. Any Ideas?

```
 Sub find()
 Dim rgFound As Range

 Dim Index As Long: Index = 6


 Do While Worksheets("July").Cells(Index, "C").Value > 0

    Set rgFound = Worksheets("Total").Range("A1:A20000").Find(Worksheets("July").Cells(Index, "C").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)


    If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then

        Row = rgFound.Row + 5


        Worksheets("Total").Range("E" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("Z" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("F" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("AA" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("G" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("AB" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("H" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("M" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("J" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("AF" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("I" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("AC" & Index).Value
        Worksheets("Total").Range("K" & Row).Value = Worksheets("July").Range("J" & Index).Value
        Index = Index + 1
    Else

            Dim lastRow As Long
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Sheets("Total").Cells

            lastRow = Last(1, rng)

            Dim Counter As Long: Counter = 1

            Do While Counter < 13

                 lastRow = lastRow + 1
                 Worksheets("Total").Range("A" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("July").Cells(Index, "C").Value
                 Worksheets("Total").Range("B" & lastRow).Value = Worksheets("July").Cells(Index, "B").Value

                 Counter = Counter + 1

            Loop

            Counter = 1



    End If


        Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your number entered into both the search range and the search value cell directly?  Or are they the result of a formula?  If the latter, you probably have a rounding issue.

Comment: `.Find` normally does not have type problems with numbers but you could try `.Find(CLng(value))`

Comment: Why have you deleted your old question and re-posted it? It's not much incentive to help.

Comment: @Jordan Try using the example on [Range.Find Method Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff839746.aspx)? That uses `Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress`